# wget returns 404 error

Tags: http, wget, https

I'm in the process of mirroring a website:
https://matic.work

I tried `wget` on Windows 10 with different options and all of them return `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-04-04 06:49:57 ERROR 404: Not Found.` for different links on the website.

The command I used is `wgetdown>wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows https://matic.work`

When I launch the local index file, the website properly displays for not even half of a second and then it shows 404 Error: This page could not be found.

What should I do?

Comment: 404 indicates that the server exists but tells you that the page(s) you attempted to fetch do not exist. Without seeing the precise command line you sent, we can only tell you that it's probably not lying.

Comment: I tried to open this link on my browser and I got 404. I believe there is nothing in it...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado That's odd. That site is an uploaded mirror site. The actual site is `https://matic.network` I get the same error with the original site.

Comment: You mean you manage to download the site but then when you open the page you have copied it redirects to a URL which is a 404?

Comment: @tripleee Correct. The local copy shows the 404 error displayed on the page. I even used HTTrack and the same problem persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site pulls in a heap of JavaScript, some of which probably contains a redirect. Try opening the page with JavaScript disabled. Works as designed.

Comment: Disable it through the browser or on my laptop in general?

Comment: Just temporarily in your browser -- perhaps create a separate profile for testing, or even install a different browser just so you can play around. If installing a plugin is acceptable, NoScript gives you a great deal of control.

Comment: Will try that and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Great. That worked!

Comment: one last question, if that local copy were uploaded to another domain, would that redirect error fix itself? Otherwise, I wouldn't be able to see it on that domain without disabling Javascript right? I'm just trying to make sure I 100% understand the root cause.

Comment: I have not examined where it redirects, but you should be able to tell easily from the browser's address bar after you get the 404.